# jQuery - stop/ start a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've setup a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bd53ewoh/

When you hover over the ".homepage-modules" container is it possible to stop the "next" function so it stops cycling the active state and when you hover off the container the "next" function starts firing again? I'm a bit stumped at the moment and not sure of a way to do this

```
$('.homepage-modules div:first').addClass('active');

$.fn.cycle = function (timeout, cls) {
    var l = this.length,
        current = 0,
        prev = 0,
        elements = this;

    if (this.filter('.active').length > 0) {
        current = this.index(this.filter('.active')[0]) + 1;
        prev = current - 1;
    }

    function next() {
        elements.eq(prev).removeClass('active');
        elements.eq(current).addClass('active');
        prev = current;
        current = (current + 1) % l;
        setTimeout(next, timeout);
    }
    setTimeout(next, timeout);
    return this;
};

$('.homepage-modules div').cycle(2000, 'active');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the result of your `setTimeout` calls in a variable within your plugin. When the mouse is over your element you can use `clearTimeout` to stop the timer running, and when the mouse moves out you can start the timer again.

```
$.fn.cycle = function (timeout, cls) {
    var l = this.length,
        current = 0,
        prev = 0,
        elements = this,
        timerId;

    if (this.filter('.active').length > 0) {
        current = this.index(this.filter('.active')[0]) + 1;
        prev = current - 1;
    }

    this.parent().hover(function(){
        clearTimeout(timerId);    
    },
    function(){
        timerId = setTimeout(next, timeout);          
    })

    function next() {
        elements.eq(prev).removeClass('active');
        elements.eq(current).addClass('active');
        prev = current;
        current = (current + 1) % l;
        timerId = setTimeout(next, timeout);
    }
    timerId = setTimeout(next, timeout);
    return this;
};
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bd53ewoh/24/

Answer (score 1):

You need a `.hover()` for your `.homepage-modules` div, and a simple boolean to handle the hover-state:

```
var noScrolling = false;

$('.homepage-modules').hover(
    function() {
        noScrolling = true;
    },

    function() {
        noScrolling = false;
        $('.homepage-modules div').cycle(2000, 'active');
    }
);
```

And then, within your `next()` function:

```
function next() {
    if (noScrolling) {
        console.log('I shouldn\'t be scrolling through.');
        return;
    }

    //  Otherwise, continue
```

Note that because I've thrown a `return` into your `next()` function, it actually returns out of the whole `$fn.cycle` parent function, hence why it's reinitialized when hovering out of the div.

I've updated your Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bd53ewoh/10/

Comment: This works, but its a very non-plugin-ey way to resolve an issue with a plugin. They should be self-contained and not rely on global variables.

Comment: @Jamiec This is true and a fair point... but it *does* work ;) The only point I'd raise with your answer (which is a better self-contained script) is that the hoever targets the child `div`s rather than the parent `.homepage-modules`. If there are any gaps or elements blocking that hover on the children, it won't fire as expected.

Comment: no it doesnt, look again. (`this.parent().hover(...)`)

Comment: @Jamie - Sorry, you're right - clearly too early for me. Although for true pluginability that might cause issues if the target of `.cycle` isn't a direct child of the hover target. In this case I can't imagine that matters too much, but worth pointing out.